# Can I round aggregation metrics in OpenSearch/Kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I created a simple DataTable visualization in OpenSearch Dashboard (which is basically Kibana in AWS). I want table with average time per user. So I group by user, and use "Average" metric. It works great, but! the log has time in milliseconds, with 3 decimal places. Can I round it (or even truncate If necessary) these 3 decimal places?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go to `Stack Management` > `Advanced Settings` > `Number format` to set decimals (in general, not for an individual visualization):

[image]

Otherwise, you could create a Table using the Time Series Visual Builder (TSVB) editor where you have the possibility to set the decimals through `Options` tab > choose 'Custom' for the `Data Formatter` > set the desired 'Numeral.js' `Format string`:

[image]